# Store increasing number sublists of a list in a vector

Tags: c++, list, pointers, vector

I have a linked list class:

```
template <class T> class List {
  private:
    struct node {
      T info;
      node* next;
      node* prev;
    };
    int length;
    node* first;
    node* last;
   ...
}
```

And i have to add a function that takes the sublists of increasing or equal numbers and stores rhem in a std::vector.
Example: if the list is: (1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3), v[0] = (1, 2, 3), v[1] = (2, 3, 3).
the header of the function is:

```
void parts(std::vector<List>& v) {}
/* Pre: v.size() == 0
 * Post: The original list is empty, v.size() = number of sublists, 
 * v[i] is the ith sublist */
```

I have found myself a solution, but i have used v.push_back() to add every sublist to the vector, but my teacher said that i can't use it and i don't know how to do it without push_back().
Thanks.

Comment: Your teacher is a moron.

Answer (score 0):

there are a bevy of other methods to add to/initialize vectors. You can pass it a range of iterators from your list, for one:

```
vector<int> v(list.begin(), list.end();
```

You can substitute any valid iterator for [beginning, end)